# Jclouds Rackspace Cloud Files service net

Tags: java, jclouds, rackspace-cloudfiles, private-network

Is it possible to use the servicenet when using the cloud files api in Java? Currently I'm using it as follows:

```
ContextBuilder cb = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(config.getProvider())
    .credentials(config.getUserName(), config.getApiKey()).modules(modules);
CloudFilesApi cfa = cb.buildApi(CloudFilesApi.class);
```

I'm asking this because I used to use the python client which has a boolean parameter in order to choose whether to use the public or the service net:

```
cf = pyrax.connect_to_cloudfiles(region=CDN_REGION, public=CDN_USEPUBLIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module> of(new SLF4JLoggingModule(),
        new InternalUrlModule());

ContextBuilder builder = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(PROVIDER)
        .modules(modules)
        .credentials(username, apiKey);
  blobStore = builder.buildView(RegionScopedBlobStoreContext.class).getBlobStore(REGION);
  cloudFiles = blobStore.getContext().unwrapApi(CloudFilesApi.class);
```

You need to make sure to add the InternalUrlModule to the list of modules. This in turn will make jclouds use the applicable ServiceNet endpoints when connecting to the service.